# PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT) vs PostQuitMessage(0)

Tags: windows, api, winapi

What is the differences between

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
    break;
```

and

```
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you call `PostQuitMessage`, you pass an exit code, not a message ID.  `PostQuitMessage` will in turn generate (and post) the `WM_QUIT` message for you.

So technically, the difference is that with `PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT)`, the exit code will be `0x0012` (or 18 in decimal).  Whereas `PostQuitMessage(0)` will provide an exit code of `0`.

When either `GetMessage` and `PeekMessage` see a `WM_QUIT` message, they will return zero, and you can check for the exit code in the `WPARAM` part of the `LPMSG` parameter.

To return the exit code (the value you pass to PostQuitMessage) the message pump for your application could be something like this:

```
MSG msg;
while (0 != GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return msg.wParam;
```

Comment: Does PostQuitMessage(0) more efficient?

Comment: They are both the same, the parameter you pass simply states what the WPARAM part of the WM_QUIT message will be.

Comment: Why would you be worried about the efficiency of exiting the program?

Comment: Excellent answer, but the sample code is slightly flawed.  GetMessage can return -1 on failure.  This message pump could try to process an uninitialized `msg` (or re-dispatch the last good one) if GetMessage returns an error.  On the other hand, since you aren't filtering the messages, an error is impossible (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/22/10404367.aspx).

Comment: I'm using Raymond Chens approach of not adding error checking in the example.

Comment: *According to the docs (for whatever that's worth)*, `PeekMessage` has the following behavior: "If a message is available, the return value is nonzero." So only `GetMessage` has the behavior you describe above.

Answer (score 1):

We can find code, on which the message loop is discontinued on an "error" of -1 from
GetMessage(). So if the application in this case suddenly disappears, no shocked user
will find out what the reason for this was. The better way is to keep the app running.
And also a "bad" message does not damage the DefWindowProc() function.